# a variable of type char* that can change value during iteration

Tags: c

I am reading a file and I would like to have a variable `word` of type `char*` such that `word` doesn't always have the same value. 
For example if I do the following :

```
FILE* file = fopen("file.txt", "r");
char line[255] = "";
char* word; 

if (file != NULL){
    while (fgets(line, 255, file) != NULL){
        word = line; 
    }
}
```

I get an error since word cannot be change like that. So how can I modify my programme so that word take the value line at each iteration ?

I tried something with malloc but it still doesn't work :

```
FILE* file = fopen("file.txt", "r");
char line[255] = "";
char* word; 

if (file != NULL){
    while (fgets(line, 255, file) != NULL){
        word = malloc(strlen(line)+1);
        word = line; 
    }
}
```

Comment: What error do you get? Please post the exact error message

Comment: You obviously need an array of words to begin with

Comment: And with `word = x; word = y;`, you are essentially storing only the latter (while the former - a pointer to an allocated block of memory in your code - is lost forever).

Comment: Your second logic has word changing every time, Try printing inside the while this statement to observe the changes `printf("%s\n",word); `